# Get data in Main class using Observer pattern

Tags: java, json, callback, observer-pattern

I'm getting JSON data from a remote API. For this I'm using the Observer pattern. I created an Observer called WordTranslationObserver that gets the JSON data from the callback method. The problem is that I don't know how to get this data in the Main class...

In my Main class I can't implement PropertyChangeListener and use a translationModel.addChangeListener(this) because I'm in a static context, so "this" can't work.

What is the proper way to be able to get my data from translation.getText() in my Main class ?

**Main class**

```
public class Main    {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        WordTranslation wordTranslation = new WordTranslation();
        WordTranslationObserver myObserver = new WordTranslationObserver(wordTranslation);
        wordTranslation.translate("sắt", "vie", "eng");     

    }
}
```

**Observer**

```
public class WordTranslationObserver implements PropertyChangeListener {
    public WordTranslationObserver(WordTranslation translationModel) {
        translationModel.addChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Changed property: " + event.getPropertyName());
        ArrayList<Translation> translations = (ArrayList<Translation>) event.getNewValue();

        // Print recieved data from JSON to the console 
        // I want to be able to get translation.getText() in my Main class
        for (Translation translation : translations) {
            System.out.println(translation.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

**Data**

```
public class WordTranslation {
    public static final String TRANSLATIONS = "translations";
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://deu.hablaa.com/hs/translation/";
    private List<PropertyChangeListener> listener = new ArrayList<PropertyChangeListener>();
    ArrayList<Translation> translations;    

     public void addChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener newListener) {
            listener.add(newListener);
     }


     public void notifyListeners(String property, Translation[] translationArray) {
            translations = new ArrayList<>();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (Translation t : translationArray) {
                translations.add(t);
            }
            for (PropertyChangeListener name : listener) {
                name.propertyChange(new PropertyChangeEvent(this, "translations", null, translations));
        }
    } 

     public void translate(String word, String from, String to) {
            final Translation[][] translations = new Translation[1][1];

            String url = String.format("%s%s/%s-%s",BASE_URL, word, from, to);//  args) "http://xxx";
        System.out.println(url);
        final Gson gson = new Gson();

        // should be a singleton
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                             .url(url)
                             .build();


        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                }

                translations[0] = gson.fromJson(response.body().charStream(),Translation[].class);  
                notifyListeners(TRANSLATIONS,translations[0]);

            }
            });

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an observer set static variables if you really wanted to, that could be polled for changes but this would defeat the principle of using the observer pattern which is event driven.

Perhaps there is some specific reason why you want this information available in the main class but I would be more inclined to offload any processing onto observers as you have already (cleanly) done, adding new implementations as you need them.

If you just want the information available to your main class (not necessarily in a static context), have your Main class implement PropertyChangeListener and register a new Main() with your WorldTranslation in the same way you have done with the WorldTranslationObserver.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's helpful.